# incorrect sudo password ansible

Tags: ssh, ansible, sudo, hashicorp-vault

In my ansible run i am getting the following error:

```
PLAY [test hashi vault] ******************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:988: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'vault.domain'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning,
ok: [192.168.1.200]

TASK [show bar] **************************************************************************************************************
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:988: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'vault.domain'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning,
fatal: [192.168.1.200]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Incorrect sudo password"}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************
192.168.1.200                : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

i know that the password is correct having done a debug and the same password works when extracting from vault using curl. this is the new code were i get the error:

```
---
- name: test hashi vault
  hosts: all
  remote_user: ec2-user
  tasks:
  - name: show bar
    systemd:
      state: restarted
      name: sssd.service
    async: 45
    become: yes
    become_method: sudo
```

this is what im running:

```
ansible-playbook -l 192.168.1.200 test.yml --private-key=/home/rehna/.ssh/testKeyPair.pem --vault-password-file /etc/ansible/ansible.vault -e @credentials
```

contents of credentials:

```
ansible_user: ec2-user
ansible_become_pass: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=secret/test/ec2_password auth_method=userpass username={{vault_user}} password={{vault_password}}  url={{vault_url}}:{{vault_port}} validate_certs=false') }}"
```

hosts

```
[ec2]
192.168.1.200
[test_env]
192.168.1.200 remote_user=ec2-user
```

from /var/log/secure:

```
unix_chkpwd[30174]: password check failed for user (ec2-user)
sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=ec2-user  uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/4 ruser=ec2-user rhost=  user=ec2-user
sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [ec2-user]
```

should be like this:

```
     sudo: ec2-user : TTY=pts/4 ; PWD=/home/ec2-user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/passwd --stdin ec2-user
     sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ec2-user(uid=0)
     sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Comment: The varialble is `ansible_become_password` (the one that is commented out....)

Comment: that doesn't make any difference @Zeitounator

Comment: You are not providing enough debugging info to answer.

Comment: i added some more info @Zeitounator

Comment: It is still not enough. For example, we don't know which exact task is failing (it might be one in your playbook you don't even show in partial paste...), which user your are connecting as, which user you are escalating privilege as. Setting a sudo password in a set_fact task is quite strange actually. You usually set that in your playbook vars, even better in your inventory. I suspect you are not even reaching that task. One thing I can state for sure is that you are giving a wrong password (or not at all)

Comment: Once again, the variable is `ansible_become_password` not `ansible_become_pass`.

Comment: tried that no difference i did a debug on ansible_become_password just before th task and defnitely has the correct sudo password

Comment: What do you have in your inventory ?

Comment: just one host as above

Answer (score 0):

the format of the data returned is dict key/value pairs.
you need to extract the content from the return data provided by the lookup:

```
ec2_pass: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=secret/test/ec2_password auth_method=userpass username={{vault_user}} password={{vault_password}}  url={{vault_url}}:{{vault_port}} validate_certs=false') }}"

ansible_become_pass: "{{ec2_pass.value}}"
```